# Delete entity in core data

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am trying to delete an entity in core data.

I use the following code:

```
        //update core data
        [context deleteObject:myEntity];
        [myEntity deleteInContext:context];

        [context save:&error];
```

So far I know that actually one of the delete lines should do the job, however none of them does. Nothing happens at all. No error message. Nothing happens.
context is my NSManagedObjectContext.

Can anyone help me?
Thank you!!!!!

Comment: Any hints if you use `NSLog(@"Context: %@, Entity: %@", context, myEntity);`?

Comment: thats the output:
Context: (null), Entity: <myEntity: 0x80827b0> (entity: myEntity; id: 0x8099240 <x-coredata://F5501461-A354-431B-9679-7AE0987531ED/myEntity/p5> ; data: {
    done = nil;
    item = "Tree";
})

Comment: If context is null then that would be the biggest hint you need.

Comment: In the same code I am editing one attribute of my entity and context is there null as well. But there it works.

Comment: You're trying to delete a (managed) _object_, not an entity.

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happens? Have you verified if the entity stills exists when you relaunch the application?

Comment: yes. the entity still exists and I know for sure that the code is being executed since all debugging NSLogs are being showed on the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In consideration of your result from logging the context: (null), the fix has to be to use a valid context.

Answer (score 4):

`[context deleteObject:myEntity]` is enough to delete an object. `[myEntity deleteInContext:context]` is redundant.

If you want the changes to be visible at once, do [context processPendingChanges], otherwise the object will be marked as "to be deleted", but the changes will be processed in the end of the runloop cycle.

Comment: thank you! however your suggestion does not solve my problem. my code is now:
             [context deleteObject:myEntity];
            NSLog(@"context is now %@", context);
            [context processPendingChanges];
            [context save:&error];

Comment: Can you show log output of myEntity.managedObjectContext as well? Since it seems that your context is nil (which it indeed should not).